# irobot create package/stack

Tags: create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI
I have a irobot create and BAM so that I can connect my laptop to irobot create via bluetooth.

I browsed software on ROS site and find a few packages/stacks that are for irobot Create. But they are all for some kind of modified Create (such as add-on camera, laser range finer, etc).

Is there any package that is purely for the barebone irobot Create that I can try?
Any recommendations.

Thank you.
Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44766/irobot-create-package/stack/) by [Jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3171/jackie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out: http://wiki.ros.org/irobot_create_2_1

For the iRobot Create 2, I'm actually working on a barebones here: https://github.com/lucbettaieb/create_2_drivers

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0